# What's better, property of a class or local variable passed through methods?

Tags: java, class

If a variable is passed through multiple methods, yet only used in one of the last ones; is it better to declare this variable as a property of a class?

I feel this question is better asked by examples, so:
Example #1

```
public class eg1 {
    private int circleSize;

    void a() {
        circleSize = ...
        b();
    }

    void b() {
        ...
        c();
    }

    void c() {
        ... circleSize ...
    }
}
```

Example #2

```
public class eg2 {
    void a() {
        int circleSize = ...
        b(circleSize);
    }

    void b(int circleSize) {
        ...
        c(circleSize);
    }

    void c(int circleSize) {
        ... circleSize ...
    }
}
```

Is there a certain way that should be used? Why?

**Edit:** Seems this question is situational, and opinion based. Some good points have been made for doing it either way.

Comment: This is opinion based, so I've voted to close it.  However, my opinion is that it really depends what kind of thing the class is intended to represent.  If the class represents some kind of real-world thing that intuitively has a "circle size" (or whatever), then keep `circleSize` as a field.  But if "circle size" isn't really part of the real-world objects represented by the class, then pass it from method to method.

Comment: It's depends on which result you need, in first case it's will be stored in instance of your class and can be accessed by each method in it (private), 2nd way give ability to reuse these methods from other classes or with different values (package-private). but my opinion that at first you need to decide where you're going to use this value

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem In this particular case it's for a circle that bounces around a scene in javaFX; so the circle belongs to the class but the circleSize doesn't, it belongs to the circle. Which is why I thought it could / should be created locally. As reconnect said by passing the variable through the methods it allows for them to be reused; however it seems a messier way of doing things and maybe doesn't help readability of code?

Comment: Don't duplicate the value if you've already got some kind of circle field.  Don't pass anything round.  When you need the circle size, retrieve it from the circle.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Good point; bad example on my part. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only going to use that variable in one method, then there is no need for you to make it private, which exposes it to all other methods. **By choosing to pass the variable instead of making it private**:

1. You avoid exposing it to other methods
2. Your code is easier to read, since you won't be looking to see where the variable is changed
3. You avoid having unnecessary attributes for your class

Answer (score 1):

The answer is very broad, but as a rule you could follow Law of Demeter:

> - Each unit should have only limited knowledge about other units: only    units "closely" related to the current unit.
> - Each unit should only    talk to its friends; don't talk to    strangers.
> - Only talk to your immediate friends.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter

So, on this particular case, use arguments. The resultant app will be more testable and easier to understand.

Comment: I hadn't heard of this law before... Or I'd forgotten it existed :) Thank you.

Comment: It's pre Object Oriented Software :)